# How to convert BLOB to Image

Tags: c#, image, arrays, blob, picturebox

I have a problem in displaying the picture which is stored in my MySQL database.
I don't know if I have stored it successfully but using this function which converts image to a blob file, here is the function:

```
private byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

When I check my database, it says BLOB with blue highlight. Now, I would like to display the image in my picturebox. I have also a function to convert byte array to image..

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    ms.Position = 0;
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

When I run the application, it says:

> ArgumentException was unheld, Parameter is not valid

I have tried using this syntax:

```
pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(dr["img"] as byte[]);
```

Or I'm thinking if I should convert BLOB to Byte Array first? then use the function to convert the byte array into Image?
when I click the name, it should display the information, unfortunately, I'm receiving the argument exception..

```
int i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
string firstname = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string lastname = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

Connection connect = new Connection();
MySqlConnection mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection(connect.connString());
mySqlConnect.Open();

string s = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE username = '" + label1.Text + "' and (fname = '" + firstname + "' and lname = '" + lastname + "')";

MySqlCommand mySQL = new MySqlCommand(s, mySqlConnect);
mySQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySqlDataReader dr = mySQL.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr.Read();
    txtFname.Text = dr["fname"].ToString();
    txtLname.Text = dr["lname"].ToString();
    txtBday.Text = dr["birthday"].ToString();
    txtEmail.Text = dr["email"].ToString();
    txtMobile.Text = dr["mobile"].ToString();
    txtAddress.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
    txtNotes.Text = dr["notes"].ToString();
    pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(dr["img"] as byte[]);
}
```

Comment: Where is the ArguementException being thrown, in the first or second bit of code? Also, how are you retrieving the data from the database?

Comment: If you run this in the debugger, you should be given an option to inspect the ArgumentException. This should a) give you the *name* of the argument that's not valid, and b) a stack trace that shows *shere* it is being thrown. Without knowing one or both of these pieces of information, we could be guessing for days.

Comment: Can you tell what `dr["img"].GetType()` returns?

Comment: @Mehmet Ataş it says system.byte[]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to convert a Bitmap and Png Image to text and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368757/easy-way-to-convert-a-bitmap-and-png-image-to-text-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
byteArrayToImage(dr.GetSqlBytes(dr.GetOrdinal("img")).Buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArgumentException was unheld, Parameter is not valid` is due to corrupt image. Your image did not save correctly. Save `byte[]` you have received in some file in the disk and try to rename it as `.jpg` or `.png` and try to open.

Corruption of binary data happens due to various reasons, `Length` of binary data wasn't saved or trimmed. If your database is configured to store `5kb` someone wrote code to trim data to `5kb` instead of raising exception or appending buffer wasn't coded correctly resulting in missing last few bytes.