# Load standart output and parse it to Image

Tags: c#, process, stream, graphviz

I have graphviz `dot.exe` file that I call with parameter `-Tpng` (output type is png, but I don't care if it is in png, bmp, or any other). I start it in C# code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = path;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.Arguments = "-Tpng";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

Then, I write input

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
```

`input` is defined before, it's a string. Input is valid, tested manually.

Then, I need to read output that graphviz prints into standart output and parse it to `Image`.

I've tried to read memory stream, but I was either unable to read it, or, after reading, the memory stream was locked (threw exception when tried `Image.FromStream(myMemoryStream);`).
I was able to load output to string

```
string output = "";
while (true)
{
     string newOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
     output += newOutput;
     if (newOutput == String.Empty)
        break;
}
```

I've tried to parse this string as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368757/easy-way-to-convert-a-bitmap-and-png-image-to-text-and-vice-versa), but it threw exception (string is not valid).

How can I get `Image` from the `dot.exe` output?

Comment: If it returns binary data reading it as an string will corrupt the result.

Comment: Check this, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143281/capturing-binary-output-from-process-standardoutput

Comment: @Gusman Ok, thanks. How can I load the image? Loading it directly via `StandartOutput.BaseStream` takes eternity - loading the stream never ends. Used: `Image.FromStream(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream);`

Comment: First of all, what do you write to Input? If you're sending also binary data it should be also corrupted. And second, read it like a file in blocks, there are thousands of examples.

Comment: @Gusman I just write write string into standart input - `p.StandartInput.WriteLine(stringInput);`. The input is valid, and if I run the file via cmd with parameters `-Tpng -Otest`, new .png file is created, so I know, input is valid. When I do not write the parameter `-O...`, instead of saving to file, the stream is redirected to standart output. And I need to capture it.

Comment: @Gusman One more thing - the output never ends. When I want to read output as string, there is no end of it, it just returns "" forever. The same with stream I try to read. `p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream` always returns, I'm not at end of stream yet.

Comment: p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream always returns true or false?

Comment: @Gusman it always returns false

Comment: Then the process isn't terminating, it must be waiting something from the input. Redirect only standard input, let the system create the console window and check what's happening.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it waits for another input. What can I do with it? Only read the response and exit when the response is over? Btw here is the part of output I get: `ÔŐŐ©QŁ€¬­J©RĄJţÍ›7dggËţ–¶ii=zýú5oßľ%•`... This is how the very long output looks.

Comment: Well, you must provide the missing input and then read the stream, `Image.FromStream(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream)` should be enough.

Comment: @Gusman Wait, how do you mean it? I do this: 1) I write to standart input 2) I try to read (and the reading state never ends). The program reads unlimited number of inputs untill closed manually.

Comment: I don't know what you write when you execute it manually, so I have no clue...

Comment: Just a guess, after writting to StandardInput close it, the program should consider the stream closing as the end of the input

Comment: The program works this way: - I input some text. If it is valid, it throws back stream. If it is not valid (and it **is** valid), it throws back error message. After this, the program waits and just consumes and throws away all the input.

Comment: @Gusman Do you mean like this? `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
                p.Close();
                return Image.FromStream(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream);` This throws exception, beacuse I try to read stream after the process is closed. When I try to read stream before the process is closed, the stream is infinitelly long.

Comment: No, I mean `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(input); p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();`

Comment: @Gusman It works! Thanks, you saved me :) You can write this as answer and I will mark it (after 5-10 minutes, or what is the cooldown for marking as best answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems the program is expecting the `StandardInput` to be finished before returning the content. Close the `StandardInput` to achieve it:

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(input); 
p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
```